# Cucumber and Watir suddenly stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, webdriver, watir

I have been using Cucumber all day and even though I did not change any files, it just stopped working.

It gives me an error that reads:

`Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)`

Any idea, what is going on?

Comment: This literally just happened to me also. Perhaps this is some time-specific development bug?

Comment: Wow everything worked find and all of a suden is not working and i am using capybara and rspec. Same error, not signs of whats going on. Terrible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a Update brew

`brew update`

`brew upgrade`

and you should be good

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simple step-by-step that should get everything working again on OS X:

1. Download the latest prebuilt chromedriver server for OS X here: http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
2. Move the chromedriver executable to your PATH. If you saved (and unzipped) chromedriver to your Downloads folder in step 1, try this (subbing your username for `<your_username>`:

   ```
   sudo cp /Users/<your_username>/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/bin
   ```
3. Profit!

`/usr/bin` should definitely work as your PATH, but you can double check all available PATHs by typing `$PATH` into Terminal.app and hitting enter.

Answer (score 4):

Today Selenium stopped working for me in Mac Os. I am using python and I am getting:

> "Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'" error.

Solution: Please update your driver file.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that Chrome updated silently in the background. Make sure you have the latest [selenium-webdriver gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver) and [chromedriver](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list).

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this. Updated chromedriver to version=21.0.1180.4 and it worked. NOte: I didn't updated selenium, Im still on selenium-webdriver (2.22.2).

Answer (score 3):

Željko Filipin  is right, I fixed this issue by downloading the new binary. Apparently there was a silent update for chrome.

Replace the binary:

http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Comment: This worked for me as well on Ubuntu. I just downloaded the 64 bit version from the URL above and replace the "chromedriver" file in my /usr/local/bin/ folder. After that everything was working fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For all who installed using homebrew: it seems that there isn't the latest version available.

Download the zip file from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list, unzip, and do `sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/20.0.1133.0/bin` to replace the current with the latest version (the version in the path won't reflect the actual chromedriver's version this way, but hey, it's working again until homebrew updates its recipe for chromedriver).

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew now has the latest chromedriver, so if you're using homebrew, all you need to do is

```
$ brew unlink chromedriver
$ brew install chromedriver
```